Using biber-ms instead of biber
I want to use the biber-ms and biblatex-ms packages. I have them installed via miktex.
I am not sure how to actually call on them instead of the original bibtex packages in my document...
I have:
\usepackage[style=numeric,autolang=other, bibencoding =utf8,backend=biber,url=true,natbib,giveninits=true,language=auto,sorting=none]{biblatex}
DO i need to edit something here?

At least you have to change biblatex into biblatex-ms. For more see the biblatex-ms manual. And don't forget to run biber-ms instead of biber.

It seems like the issues I am having are less with biber than with my compiler tectonic. So yes. Just changing to biblatex-ms is enough.
